# Creating/Accessing Global object with requirejs and backbonejs

Tags: javascript, object, backbone.js, requirejs, global

This is presented in easy to understand fashion, so enjoy reading :)

I have a backbone app which is initialised with main.js file like this:

```js
require([
    'backbone',
    'app',
    'models/session'
], function (Backbone, Application, SessionModel) {


    //new Application();
    window.App = {
      session: new SessionModel()
    };

    new Application();

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

As you can see, requirejs requires 'app' as a second param.

App is just a router which looks something like this (less important parts has been removed)

```
define(function(require){
    'use strict';

    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        Header = require('views/header'),
        Login = require('views/login');

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        initialize: function(){
            this.header = new Header();
            this.header.render();
        },


        routes: {
            'login': 'showLogin'
        },

        showLogin: function() {
            this.showView(new Login(), {requiresAuth: false});
            this.header.model.set('title', 'Login');
        },

        showView: function(view, options) {

            if(this.currentView) this.currentView.remove();
            $('.content').html(view.render().$el);
            this.currentView = view;

            return view;
        }

    });

    return Router;
});
```

The important bit here is that in the first lines I'm requiring

```
Header = require('views/header');
```

Header view requires another view in a standard way:

```
LogoutView = require('views/logout');
```

Logout view looks like this and here I come to the essence of the problem :

```
define(function(require){
    'use strict';

    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        JST = require('templates')

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.session,

        template: JST['app/scripts/templates/logout.hbs'],

        events: {
            'submit form': 'logout'
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)
        },

        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

            return this;
        },

        logout: function(e){
            //nothing important here
        }

    });
});
```

As you can see at the very first line after Backbone.View.extend I'm trying to define the model property of the view:

```
model: App.session,
```

which I suppose should be accessible, because I was defining the:

```
window.App = {
      session: new SessionModel()
    };
```

in the main.js file.

But it seems that there is a require problem, because as require is trying to get all the files in the first lines of the program:

```
require([
    'backbone',
    'app', <<--- in this line it's trying to get all the files required in the app.js 
    'models/session'
], function (Backbone, Application, SessionModel) {
```

Then I'm getting this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined   logout.js:8
```

Which is exactly the line trying to get access to App global variable:

```
 model: App.session,
```

That should be defined after running main.js file, but it doesn't even go that far as require is getting the files and finds not defined App variable in the LogoutView.

I can work around this problem by defining the model inside the initialize function of the view like so:

```
initialize: function(){
    this.model = App.session;
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render)
},
```

But what I really want is to understand why this error is occurring and what is the best practice of creating global Models using Backbone.js and Require.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of dependencies in a `define` or `require` (the first argument in your `require` or the [simplified wrapper](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) you use in your other modules) tells RequireJS that it should load and **interpret** those modules before interpreting the current file.

Here's what happens:

1. The first `require` has `backbone`, `app`, `models/session` as dependencies
2. before its function is evaluated, it loads its dependencies and in turn looks for their dependencies
3. Rinse and repeat until you reach `views/logout`
4. `views/logout` is interpreted, you try to assign `App.session` to your `view.model` but that does not exist at that point and you get a `App is not defined` error

---

One solution would be to create a singleton of your `Session` object and require it when you need it.

For example, let's say you have `globals/session`

```
define(['models/session'], function (SessionModel) {
    return new SessionModel();
});
```

You would define your app as

```
require([
    'backbone',
    'app',
    'globals/session'
], function (Backbone, Application, session) {

    //new Application();
    window.App = {
      session: session
    };

    new Application();

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

and the same change in your `view/logout`

```
define(function(require){
    'use strict';

    var Backbone = require('backbone'),
        JST = require('templates')

    return Backbone.View.extend({
        model: require('globals/session'),
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer, I knew what was happening, but thanks for the bullet points, it will help others with the issue for sure.

So what you are saying is that, there is no way to have a global variable outside of the requirejs scope and you need to attach it within it?

Comment: You can have global variables, you just have to be aware of the order in which the files are included. I prefer to have a module dedicated to those variables that I can include at will and that does not pollute the global scope.

Comment: Yes, I meant having variables in the global scope without polluting it, which is a bit contradictory statement. But yes you are right, it's better not to pollute the global scope. Thanks for clearing that out!

Oh yes, and one more thing, is it a singleton that you showed in the first code snippet ? It looks like it returns new SessionModel (NEW) every time you are requiring it. Or is it some kind of requirejs magic ?

Comment: The singleton is indeed in the first snippet, the code will only be evaluated once on the first require wherever that happens. It's a kind of magic, yes:)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is more or less how I was trying to solve this problem before I've posted this question:

```
define(function(require) {
    'use strict';

    var SessionModel = require('models/session')

    var session = (function(){
        if(App.session instanceof SessionModel.constructor){
            return App.session;
        } else {
            App.session = new SessionModel()
            return App.session;
        }
    })();

    return session;
});
```

But I think I've abandoned it for some reason, either because App wasn't defined or maybe it seemed that there is a better solution for this.

The dirty hack was that I had to create the:

```
window.App = {};
```

Just before I was running the entire application.